# Web menu button to keep a different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I don't probably know how to search for this precise question and I haven't found anything, so I am sorry if there is already asked somewhere.

I only have 3 buttons and the index is the "Inicio" page. I've applied a :hover to the buttons, but I want to keep it fixed for the button of the displayed page. Obviously, I want to have "Inicio" in this state at the beginning.

(jsfiddle below)

```
<!-- menu -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <a id=inicio href=#><li class="boton"><p class="text_menu">INICIO</p></li></a>
                <a id=productos href=#><li class="boton"><p class="text_menu">PRODUCTOS</p></li></a>
                <a id=contacto href=#><li class="boton"><p class="text_menu">CONTACTO</p></li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>

#nav {
    padding-top: 27px;
    padding-left: 25%;
}

#nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 4%;

    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}

.text_menu {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.boton {

    width: 15%;
    height: 57px;

    background-color: #0099ff;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;

}

.boton:hover {
    background-color: #0033ff;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: R u using php for the page?

Comment: No, why do you ask that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can simply add class like `.hovered` to current button like

**HTML:**

```
<li class="boton hovered"><p class="text_menu">CONTACTO</p></li></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hovered {
   background-color: #0033ff;
}
```

UPD: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/7jbUj/19/)

UPD2: **For page changing**

U simply can add and remove class on `click' like:

```
$('nav ul a').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul a li.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).children('li').addClass('hovered');
})
```

[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/7jbUj/20/)

Comment: @epascarello Um.. it could be used if smth conflicts with your rule somewhere lower in cascade. When you have big stylesheets or use some kind of minifiers. And, do you have better idea for such cases?

Comment: It is horrible to use !important. Simple selector can solve the issue.

Comment: but now your code now, :hover will still change it. ;)

Comment: @epascarello Added fiddle)) Nothing changes))

Comment: @Good.luck the problem is that I use jquery to only change the content of "container" for each page, so I can't do this. I guess with advanced knowledge of javascript I could change the style for the correct page each time, but I don't have them.

Comment: @jjgonzalez Updated my answer. Use `addClass/removeClass`.

Comment: Ok I see it working on your fiddle, but when I add it to my page it doesn't :S I added it like that before the script for changing the page, isn't it right? <script type="text/javascript">
 $('nav ul a').on('click', function(){
  $('nav ul a li.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
  $(this).children('li').addClass('hovered');
 })
  </script>

Comment: @jjgonzalez It just should be after adding jquery script, and, btw, how do you change the page content? AJAX?

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko yes, It's quite strange because it works in jsfiddle and not in my environment(DW) http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/22/

Comment: @jjgonzalez could you send me content of your html head via email puzyrenkoev@gmail.com May be l'll figure smth out.

Comment: @jjgonzalez Sent you an archive

Comment: Ok I've just got the solution. The problem was that I was using jquery1.3.2 and you was using jquery2.1.1, and that's why it was working for you and not for me... Really thanks everyone for your responses and sorry for this, specially @Y.Puzyrenko . Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use without JQuery, you have to use it in javascript

HTML :

```
<a id="mnu1" class="mnu hovered" src="#" onclick="makeSelected('mnu1')"> One </a>
<a id="mnu2" class="mnu" src="#" onclick="makeSelected('mnu2')"> Two </a>
<a id="mnu3" class="mnu" src="#" onclick="makeSelected('mnu3')"> Three </a>
```

CSS :

```
.mnu{
  background-color : #451;
  margin-left:20px;
  font-size:30px;
}
a:hover{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.hovered{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

JS :

```
var prev_mnuid= "mnu1";
function makeSelected(mnuid){
  document.getElementById(prev_mnuid).className = "mnu";
  document.getElementById(mnuid).className = "mnu hovered";
  prev_mnuid=mnuid;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rajaveld/t31zc8jx/

Comment: Thank you, but I have the same problem than with the other solution. I'm probably putting JS badly because it doesn't work in my page. Don't I have to add it to a new <script> ?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? if already you have <script> then include in that

Comment: I've got 2 <script>, one for the initial load and another one below for the pages change. I added it to the second one and it works in jsfiddle but not in my page http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/22/